QGIS (qgis2web) automatically update data set
I am working on a QGIS Map with location data.
My goal is to create a web-map (intern server - not public) with my QGIS Map. My data gets updated reguarly. Currently I am working with qgis2web plugin.
(Data is just a vector imported from an .csv - goal is to update the .csv and the web-map automatically)
My data gets updated reguarly and right now it does not automatically update my data in my webmap.
Does anyone know a workaround for my issue?

Where are you pulling your data from? Is it a geoserver using a protocol like WMS? Does the CSV auto update on a server or are you just manually updating the CSV and importing it into QGIS?

Its straight up Data from an excel sheet - so if i update the excel it updates in qgis but not on my webmap

so in this excel you have two columns x and y that indicate the coordinates of the point object?

yes - coordinates and columns with Number and some info

i just want to create a Map with the points out ouf my excel - with a lable of points, search option for points numbers and a basemap

Export your project with qgis2web, enter the "layers" folder and you will find your layer exported in .js format, your goal is to schedule a routine from the command line that acquires the new .csv file and transforms it into an identical file, like form, to the one exported from qgis2web (but with the updated data obviously)
Assuming your CSV file is called input.csv and has latitude and longitude columns for coordinates, you can use ogr2ogr to do the conversion. The command line will look like this:
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" output.geojson input.csv -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=longitude -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=latitude

Once you have the output.geojson file, you can rename it to output.js:
mv output.geojson output.js

